# Adding event listeners using useRef inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm writing a React component that accepts some data as an array and renders them. However, I need to add some event listeners to it. The functions I'll be passing to the event listeners should depend on the data. Basically, the rendered items and their behavior should be completely data-driven.

I wrote this piece of code that adds event listeners, however it seems like it keeps overwriting the event listeners and I always get the function from the last iteration.

```js
const App = () => {
 const data = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
 const itemRef = React.useRef(data.map((x) => React.createRef(x)));

 React.useEffect(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < itemRef.current.length; i++) {

   // need to define a function here that will 
   // accept data[i] as a parameter.
   // That unique function would be added 
   // to event listener on each iteration 

   itemRef.current[i].current.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`clicked data:${i}`);
   });
  }
 }, []);

 return (
  <div className="App">
   {data.map((x, i) => {
    return (
     <div className='item' ref={itemRef.current[i]} key={data[i]}>
      {x}
     </div>
    );
   })}
  </div>
 );
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Ideally, in that `() => {console.log(i)}` section (inside `addEventListener`) I want to pass a function that would be unique on each iteration.

Am I taking the right approach with this? Can this code be amended so if I click on item 3 it logs 3 (not 5)?

Comment: You should always avoid calling hooks in loops. It’s against the rules of hooks as laid out by the React team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't resort to refs in this instance, an `onClick` will work, you can add in a handler, or you can define a function on the fly like below:

```js
const App = () => {
 const data = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];

 return (
  <div className="App">
   {data.map((x, i) => {
    return (
     <div className='item' onClick={()=>{console.log("item data", x)}} key={data[i]}>
      {x}
     </div>
    );
   })}
  </div>
 );
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it possible to get getComputedStyle() of a current component when defining it inline?

Comment: Yes, if you want to do that sort of thing that is where [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) can come back into it. But it would be better to then refactor out the `<div className='item' ...` into it's own component, that way each item component could call `useRef` and ref={ref} and not risk breaking the Rules of Hooks.

Comment: You could even access the style of the element directly from `ref.current` without needing `getComputedStyle`

Comment: another question for you might be able to help me with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238849/resizing-components-using-map-and-inline-event-handlers